# The Lebesgue measure of a zero set of a $C^{3}$ function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $f\in C^{3}([0,+\infty))$ be a positive strict decrease funcition satisfying $f(0)=2$ and
$$ \lim_{r\to +\infty}e^{r}f(r)=1 $$
For any given $k\geq 4$, Suppose that $\mu_{1},\ldots, \mu_{k}$ are some fixed points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, I am trying to proving that the set
$$ \bigg\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}:\sum_{j=1}^{k}f(|x-\mu_{j}|)=1\bigg\} $$
admits zero $n$-dimensional Lebesgue in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Does this conclusion holds? Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't think this will hold if $n \leq k$. Did you try out very simple examples?